# Have functions.php script in footer. Not head

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I have a JS file with a lot of functions that work with DOM manipulation. I added this hover event listener that was from W3 school and getting a 'Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null' error.

```
  let hover = document.querySelectorAll(".center-nav a");


  hover.addEventListener("mouseenter", function( event ) {   
    // highlight the mouseenter target
    event.target.style.color = "purple";

    // reset the color after a short delay
    setTimeout(function() {
      event.target.style.color = "";
    }, 500);
  }, false);
```

Did some digging and read it's due to this event is loaded before the pages HTML. Which makes sense because the main.js file is leading in the head.

My functions.php

```
function mikes_files(){
    wp_enqueue_style('main-style', get_stylesheet_uri(), NULL, microtime() );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'prefix-font-awesome', 'https://kit.fontawesome.com/xxxxx.js' );  
    wp_enqueue_script('main-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/main.js', NULL, microtime() );
}



add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mikes_files', 999);
```

Read that the 999 helps with make it load last, but its still in the head.

Do I make a different js file with the code and find the function needed that puts it in the footer?

Comment: You might want to checkout [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/37960/cant-enqueue-scripts-in-the-footer) and [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/284072/how-to-add-js-in-footer)

Comment: I'm voting to close because the `wp_enqueue_script()` documentation is pretty clear about loading in the footer: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line:

```
wp_enqueue_script('main-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/main.js', NULL, microtime() );
```

with this:

```
wp_enqueue_script('main-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/main.js', array(), microtime(), true );
```

In `wp_enqueue_script` there is an option to define whether to load the script in `<head>` or before `</body>`. By default `wp_enqueue_script` loads the script in `<head>` just pass the 5th argument to `true` to load it before `</body>`. For more details, please refer [wp_enqueue_script](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) documentation.

Also, [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) returns the NodeList and you can not call `addEventListener` using the NodeList. You should iterate over the NodeList, and apply `addEventListener` to each element.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using / can use jQuery, you would just wrap your function in `$(document).ready(function(){ **your code**});`. If you're using vanilla JS, check out [Pure JavaScript equivalent of jQuery's $.ready() - how to call a function when the page/DOM is ready for it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9899372/pure-javascript-equivalent-of-jquerys-ready-how-to-call-a-function-when-t)